# How to extract a integer from a binary string and save it in a matrix?

Tags: java

**I have a properties file that contains this information:**

```
info.row1=1100011
info.row2=1000001
info.row3=0001000
info.row4=0011100
info.row5=0001000
info.row6=1000001
info.row7=1100011
```

**Also I have a matrix like this**

```
info = new int[7][7];
```

**I want to save each int number in a part of the matrix, like this:**

```
    ---------------
    |1|1|0|0|0|1|1|
    ---------------
    |1|0|0|0|0|0|1|
    ---------------
    |0|0|0|1|0|0|0|
    ---------------
    |0|0|1|1|1|0|0|
    ---------------
    |0|0|0|1|0|0|0|
    ---------------
    |1|0|0|0|0|0|1|
    ---------------
    |1|1|0|0|0|1|1|
    ---------------
```

How can I do that? I have this code that works well until now, I just need to save that info in the matrix.

```
 private void startInfo(Properties data)
    {
        info = new int[7][7];

        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                String estate = data.getProperty( "info.row" +i );
                info[i][j] = ???????????;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the data once per row and use the `String.charAt` function to map to integers:

```
private void startInfo(Properties data) {
    info = new int[7][7];

     for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
         // only read once per row
         String estate = data.getProperty( "info.row" +i );
         for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
             // map '0' to 0, anything else to '1'
             info[i][j] = estate.charAt(j) == '0' ? 0 : 1;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: clever using the if statement to do the 'conversion' to integers...  Nicely done!

Comment: @zipzit There isn't an `if` statement there! Was that comment meant for me?

Comment: no, comment for Reut... My bad, not a pure if statement, he used the ternary operator to perform the if function.  Thats not a tool most folks reach for first. Paul, I would have done it exactly the way you did it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, altough I get a nullPointerException I dont know why. I need to save it as an integer in order to compare it later.

Comment: @zipzit Fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Character.digit(char, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-) to perform the `int` conversion. Something like

```
info = new int[7][7];
for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  String estate = data.getProperty(String.format("info.row%d", i + 1));
  char[] line = estate.toCharArray();
  for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
    info[i][j] = Character.digit(line[j], 10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using RegExs and a loop

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("=\\d*").matcher("info.row1=1100011 info.row2=1000001 info.row3=0001000 info.row4=0011100 info.row5=0001000 info.row6=1000001 <info.row7=1100011");
int[][] info = new int[7][7];
int counter = 0;

while (m.find()){
    String s = m.group(0).substring(1);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++){
        info[counter][i] = s.charAt(i);
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for the answer, you all resolved my doubt. Although, what no one realized (including me) is that my properties data started in 1, for example the first line was "info.row1", so when we started the first "for" in 0, we were searching for something that didnt exist, and a nullpointerexception error was caused. So the solution is to add 1 to i and problem solved. THANKS